# stretch ImageView vertically constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I'm having a slight problem in getting the ImageView to fill the remaining gap vertically. I have highlighted it in red on the screenshot. Could someone take a look and offer some advice?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBio1.png

This is the associated XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/happy_birthday_toyou"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/invite"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewBottom"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="@string/happy_birthday_toyou"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:gravity="start"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBottom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/from_me"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing "android:layout_height="wrap_content" in your imageView to 0dp

Comment: I swear I tried this yesterday, and it wouldn't work. Tried it just now it works fine :)

Comment: Android is a world full of magic like this. Always remember about using proper constraints, they can be tricky when trying to make your view fill layout.

Comment: Love you baby xx